# Qt Installer Framework - Install new software version

Tags: qt, qt-installer

Is there a way to install a new version of a software (with QIFW) on top of an existing one (also installed with QIFW)?

I'm building a software for a fairly big office and I'd like my users to be able to update their software without having to uninstall it every time. (I know of the QIFW online installer, I'd like to avoid it for now especially in testing phases)

I've looked around in QIFW's docs, I couldn't find anything relevant.

Comment: This part of the docs seem relevant: [Qt Installer Framework Manual: Promoting Updates](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/ifw-updates.html). Also see if any of the previous similar questions could help: [Qt installer framework update](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Qt+installer+framework+update).

Comment: The problem is all those entries are about online installers wich I'm trying to avoid.